# js.erb not executing javascript but is processed rails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to get my pagination working with Ajax, using either will_paginate or kaminari.

When I hit pagination link my log says

```
Processing by Instructor::FullDashboardController#pupil_leads as JS
```

and

```
Rendered instructor/full_dashboard/pupil_leads.js.erb within layouts/main (0.1ms)
```

But the js has no effect. So to test it I wrote

```
console.log("Hello");
<%logger.debug "This is the js file"%>
alert('Hello Rails');
```

In the js.erb file, in my log I see `This is the js file` as expected, but there is nothing in js console in my browser and the alert doesn't show. So I know the file is being processed, as my logger.debug works but there is no js.

How can I further troubleshoot this?

Rails 4.1

Ruby 2.1

Full Dash Controller

```
class Instructor::FullDashboardController < ApplicationController
   layout 'main'
...
   def pupil_leads
     @ivar = Model.where("something = ?", some_object.id).order("created_at desc").page(params[:page]).per(10)
     respond_to do |f|
       f.js { render :content_type => 'text/javascript' }
       f.html
     end
  end
```

Comment: please show full `Instructor::FullDashboardController`.

Comment: It's a bit long for that, do you want the relevant action?

Comment: post `pupil_leads` action.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Add `layout: false` option to the render block:

```
def pupil_leads
   # some code here
  respond_to do |f|
    f.js { render layout: false, content_type: 'text/javascript' }
    f.html
  end
end
```

<sub>For some reason Rails don't recognize request as `xhr`, I also watched that the views extension (`.erb.html` or `.slim`) must be specified in full.</sub>

Comment: Thank you. Can you possibly give a short explanation as to why this is needed? Just for reference.

Comment: Thanks so much, I was going totally crazy with this. One of those "wish I had asked sooner and saved a dozen hours" ones. Thanks again.

Comment: for debug async action use `Chrome/Network` response tab, here you always can see whats wrong with your server response.

Comment: Also keep in mind, a single error in your js and all may fail silently - even an initial console.log statement on the first line.  Start with only a console.log statement in your js file, then slowly add pieces back until the console.log statement doesn't appear - which means there is an untracable (in rails) bug somewhere in the latest code you pasted back.

Comment: Thank you. you saved me