# .js.erb file is not executing although rendered in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I use rails and haml. I send data via Ajax post to a controller in rails:

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: '/preview-image-upload',
processData: false,
contentType: false,
dataType : 'json',
data: data
});
```

Then I execute the data and render js in the controller:

```
respond_to do |format|
 if @previewupload.save
  format.js
 end
```

The object is saved correctly. Also the .js.erb file is correctly rendered according to the server log:

```
Rendered path/preview_image_upload.js.erb (0.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 603ms (Views: 8.1ms | ActiveRecord: 8.5ms)
```

For testing reasons, I put an alert into the preview_image_upload.js.erb file:

```
alert("Hello World");
```

but nothing happens. It looks like the .js.erb file is rendered but not executed.

Tried the solution from here:
[js.erb not executing javascript but is processed rails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27126591/js-erb-not-executing-javascript-but-is-processed-rails)

```
{ render layout: false, content_type: 'text/javascript' }
```

But that did not work.

Comment: Check `net` tab in google/chrome or firefox for response from server.

Comment: The response visible in FF Developer is "alert("Hello World");" - no errors are raised.

Comment: can you show the full code of a controller action, views ?

Comment: It may be that the js error is silent

Answer (score 3):

The datatype to execute a Rails javascript response from a jQuery AJAX call is `script`

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I simply have to remove the dataType attribute in the Ajax request. Makes it look like this:

```
$.ajax({
type: 'POST',
url: '/preview-image-upload',
processData: false,
contentType: false,
data: data
});
```